# init.js:36 GET https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/esri/WebMap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-custom-widget

I got above error in my browser developer tools window. This happened when I added esri/WebMap to my widget.js file of custom widget I was building.

Comment: Most probably it is removed from the library. Did you try the latest version, https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/WebMap.js, or do you specifically need this 3.28 library to run your widget?

Answer (score 0):

The WebMap class is new in the 4.x version of the ArcGIS API of JavaScript.

To work with webmaps in 3x version there were utility methods like *createMap* as described at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_webmap.html

Maybe you are trying to use sample code from 4x in 3x. That will not work.